# Get listview item clicked count in android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I want to count the number of clicks of particular item in list view. Suppose there are 3 items in list view and I click 1st item for 1st time, it should display toast message that 1st item clicked count is "1". Now, if I again click 1st item, message should be 1st item clicked count is "2" and so on for other items. How can I do this?

Comment: Keep an array of ints that is the same size as your list and update the appropriate index every time an item is clicked. the `onListItemClick` callback tells you which position was clicked, so this should be very easy for you.

Comment: hey my List items are dynamic...items are added to List by user inputs.

Comment: are you wanna display index of listview or clicking count?

Comment: Then use something other than an array that can change size.

Comment: kind of...I want to check condition, if any item is clicked for the first time 1st condition must be execute and if item is clicked for 2nd time and so on  2nd condituion must be execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can use `Map<String, Integer>` here to get the count for your ListView item. Just keep the default value as 0 in the Map and add 1 always inside the `onItemClick()` of ListView.

Pseudo Code,

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                                                    long arg3) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        count = map.get(your_listview_value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    map.put(your_listview_value, (count + 1));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                             String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count = myMap.get(lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
    myMap.put(lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), count+ 1);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), count, 1000).show();
   }
  });


Hey I am getting force close error on item click. What is wrong with my code?