# Keeping counter of image clicks by user

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` of images in my app, the Views are generated by an `Adapter`, I wanted to know if there was a way I can keep a counter of how many times a user has clicked a specific image in the `ListView`? also how would I be certain that the when I release an update for the app (add more images), the counters doesn't reset?

Please let me know If you want me to provide code
Thanks in advance

Comment: put a static counter inside your onClick();                     static counter;image.onclick(){counter++}

Comment: See this [link](http://code-android87.blogspot.in/2013/09/this-is-testing-for-android-code.html) for a basic counter example

Comment: if you want to individual counter of each image you should make instance variable of holder class. if you want to globe count then make it static

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030384/get-listview-item-clicked-count-in-android) too..

It says

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                                                    long arg3) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        count = map.get(your_listview_value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    map.put(your_listview_value, (count + 1));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
    String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ImageView img;//globally declared
int count;//globally declared

img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count=count+1;
            }
        });
```

and to avoid the counters to reset you can save the count value in shared preference