# How to get Count of listview Item is clicked in android

Tags: android, listview

I need to help for get how many times list item is clicked when the item is clicked. please help me. if may list item is clicked two times i want to get that item count

```
 rightList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    int len = rightList.getCount();
                    item = data1.get(position);
                    int count = rightList.indexOfChild(view);
                    int cont=0;
}
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030384/get-listview-item-clicked-count-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a hashmap

 HashMap<Integer ,Integer> hasmap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

// and on listview  onItemclick check

```
 if (hasmap.containsKey(_id))
   {
      // increment the  value if click on same listview item

      int val = Integer.parseInt(hasmap.get(product_id));
      value = val + 1;
      hasmap.put(_id, value);
   }
else
{
    // 
    hasmap.put(_id, 1);
}
```

Comment: is there _id and product_id is new variable

Comment: which value is passed to _id and product_id please tell me

Comment: sry, Here _id and product_id are same. In my case, I am fetching data from JSON and set  _id to the listview.Here id is unique number through which I am able to determine which row is clicked first time and which row clicked previously .